# Select rows in the columns on the basis of value

Tags: r

I have a .csv file with 2021  rows and 21 columns. Except for the first column, rest 20 have binary values "0" or "1". How to select rows with binary value"1" for column 2,4 and 6?

Answer (score 0):

Read your CSV file into R with, e.g., `read.csv()`.  It will be stored as a data.frame.  Then you can subset your dataframe with one of the following options:

```
# generate some example data
set.seed(1234)
df <- data.frame(
    col1 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5),
    col2 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5),
    col3 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5),
    col4 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5),
    col5 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5),
    col6 = rbinom(100, 1, 0.5))

# the long, explicit way with base R
df[df$col2 == 1 & df$col4 == 1 & df$col6 == 1, ]

# or, equivalently with "subset"
subset(df, col2 == 1 & col4 == 1 & col6 == 1)

# or with "with"
with(df, df[col2 == 1 & col4 == 1 & col6 == 1, ])

# or by changing df to a data.table
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[col2 == 1 & col4 == 1 & col6 == 1]

# or via dplyr / tidyverse
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(col2 == 1, col4 == 1, col6 == 1)

# or if you want to use lots of bad coding practices all at once :)
attach(df)
sort(which(col2 * col4*col6== 1)) ->my_fav.Rows
df[ my_fav.Rows,names(df)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the function filter of the package dplyr (tidyverse) would be very useful. Try something like this after make your database a data frame:

database %>%
filter( col2=="1", col4=="1", col6=="1").

Dont forget to install the package tidyverse and to use the pipe operator (%>%). Hope it works